# Escape emojis and then readd them using php

Tags: php

I have a code that adds a special character in certain positions of a string. The problem is that if there is an emoji in that string it will not be counted as 1 character but it depends on its size (format like "\xee\x90\x95".

So I need to temporarily remove them and then readd in the same position as before
Any Idea on how to it?

My code is like this:

```
$char_added=0;
case "bold":
    $text=substr_replace($text, '<b>', $offset+$char_added, 0);
    $char_added=$char_added+3;
    $text=substr_replace($text, '</b>', ($offset+$length+$count), 0); 
    $char_added=$char_added+4;
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

> (format like "\xee\x90\x95".

That's not the format of the string it's a 7-bit ASCII representation of the character. PHP natively uses ASCII. But strings are just data - and PHP can work with binary data in different formats - it just so happens that the original string functions in PHP only understand ASCII. You need the [mbstring extension](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php) to (properly) handle this data as strings.

```
function inject_char($str, $pos, $char_to_inject, $encoding)
{
    $pos=min($pos, mb_strlen($str, $encoding));
    return mb_substr($str, 0, $pos, $encoding)
        . $char_to_inject
        . mb_substr($str, $pos, null, $encoding);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this could help you:

```
    public static function RemoveEmoji($text)
    {
        $cleanText = "";
        
        // Match Emoticons
        $regexEmoticons = '/[\x{1F600}-\x{1F64F}]/u';
        $cleanText = preg_replace($regexEmoticons, '', $text);
        
        // Match Miscellaneous Symbols and Pictographs
        $regexSymbols = '/[\x{1F300}-\x{1F5FF}]/u';
        $cleanText = preg_replace($regexSymbols, '', $cleanText);
        
        // Match Transport And Map Symbols
        $regexTransport = '/[\x{1F680}-\x{1F6FF}]/u';
        $cleanText = preg_replace($regexTransport, '', $cleanText);
        
        return $cleanText;
    }
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/quantizer/5744907